# Returning a custom content types with meta values

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query, post-meta

I find myself facing a situation where I will have a bunch of custom post types and I want to select those with specific meta values. There is a slight wrinkle in that the value I want to select against is within a larger array stored to a single meta key.

I'm pretty sure I could write an SQL select statement using `LIKE "%$myterm:$myvalue%"` but I wondered if there was an easier way?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but if not storing the data in an array is possible, then do that. When storing an array it's saved in a "serialised" form, which is not designed for querying. You've have a much _much_ easier time (and much better performance to boot) if you save the values separately.

Comment: That's what I suspected. The data is not just `foo=>bar` but `foo=>(bar=>baz,lar=>nar)` where `foo`, `baz`, and `nar` could literally be anything. I'm halfway tempted to rejig it with a custom table - at least as an index of the `foo` vs `baz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I am understanding your correctly...If I'm way off, let me know!

```
// Assuming ideas is an array and you are looking for ideas=>two
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        // You can pass 'any' to post_type, but you get a hold of revisions, attachments, and menu_items. But I am not sure how many Custom Post Types you have ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ 
        'post_type' => array('cpt_one', 'cpt_two', 'cpt_three', 'etc'),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'ideas',
                'value' => array('one', 'two', 'three'),
                'compare' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    )
);

// ideas is still an array here, and the value of 'two' lives inside of that ideas array() 
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => array('cpt_one', 'cpt_two', 'cpt_three', 'etc'),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'ideas',
                'value' => 'two',
                'compare' => 'LIKE' // Less-known and not explained well in the docs.
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Going back to Jacob Peattie's point, querying can be heavy at times depending on the complexity of your arrays. Again, if I am off here....let me know!

Comment: From what I can tell, you are spot on. I am starting to see what you have all been saying about heavy queries. I think the best bet for me is to take this, play with it, and then profile how long it takes on my test server (aka my desktop). At least I know it can be done this way (even if it might not be wise).

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query allows you to get pretty crazy with filters and can give you back some raw SQL to use instead. It will cut out some of the fluff that WP_Query comes shipped with.

Comment: Wowsers. That page is getting added to my bookmarks.